# provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server 2012

Tags: .net, sql-server-2012, named-pipes

I'm getting the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server).

This is my code:

```
public DataTable GetAll()
    {
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("Domain_GetAll", m_Connection);
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter DAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DAdpt.Fill(ds,"Domain");**error at this location**
        return ds.Tables["Domain"];
    }
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please always provide some context and description to your question. Next time please don't simply throw error messages with code. Please refer too: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The problem could be  in your connection string. Are you sure it is valid? With the servername, user and password or your conn string, can you connect to the database with Sql management studio from the machine where your code is running?